# Differences between .NET 3.0 & 3.5?

Tags: .net, .net-3.5, .net-3.0

What are the major differences between the .NET 3.0 & 3.5 frameworks?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

ASP.NET AJAX was inbuilt  for 3.5

**.Net 3.0**

> .net 2.0 features + WF+WPF+WCF+ Cardspace

**.Net 3.5**

> .Net 3.0 features + LINQ, ASP.NET AJAX, new controls, richer WCF support (incl REST, AtomPub), and a few other features

For more details refer to: [.Net Frameworks](http://dufoli.wordpress.com/2007/09/11/net-framework-11-20-30-35-21/) that shows the difference and added features from .net frameworks 1.0 and on

Answer (score 3):

Big one is [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa904594.aspx)